# How to force reinstall of Windows Remote Server Administration tools (RSAT)? (error 0x80070005, Access Denied)

Tags: windows-10

I have patiently and faithfully reinstalled Remote Server Administration tools (RSAT) on my Windows 10 (pro) Workstation after each feature update (and Early Release build), but now it's partially broken and I'd like to do a clean reinstall, but:

- if I try to remove the existing RSAT

  - kb2693643 is not visible in control / programs / View Installed Updates
  - `c:\> WUSA /uninstall /kb:2693643`  finds the update and starts uninstalling, but fails at the end with Access Denied.  Same error in Safe Mode with no networking.
- if I try to install RSAT, I get error "this update is already installed on this computer"

This is Windows 10 Pro Ver 1709, RSAT KB2693643.

I'm down this road because e.g, DHCP works, but DNS does not...  I could probably cobble something together with files from another machine, but I'd have more confidence in a tool I depend on every day if I could do a normal install.

Can anyone suggest a hack that would make RSAT appear uninstalled so the regular installer would try to work?  `WUSA` does not have an appropriate option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Microsoft Windows Server 2019, specifically build 1809 or later, then [you need to install RSAT through Features On Demand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-server-administration-tools#when-to-use-which-rsat-version). Some people report [enabling WSUS](https://www.ajtek.ca/wsus/rsat-tools-on-1809-and-higher-other-features-on-demand-aka-optional-features/) helps, too, although it's not 100% clear why (it might depend on whether your organization uses SCCM vs. Windows Update repository for updates).

1. Go to Server Manager.
2. In the top right Manage button, select Add Roles or Features...
3. Click Next until you get to the Add Features train in the wizard
4. Select Remote Server Administration Tools, or the sub-set of features you need.

Note that scripts I found on [TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-RSAT-for-Windows-75f5f92f), as well as guides published by Packt Publishing's [Windows Server 2019 Automation with PowerShell Cookbook 3rd Ed](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/virtualization_and_cloud/9781789808537/1/ch01lvl1sec13/installing-rsat-tools-on-window-10-and-windows-server-2019), do not seem to actually work if you use SCCM like we do.  Notably, `Get-WindowsCapability -Online` only returns the set of capabilities your SCCM server allows clients to see, so these tools erroneously say that RSAT is installed, rather than verifying they're installed.

Comment: That's probably how I got into this situation: already had RSAT installed, then upgraded to 1809, Would this have migrated my install to a Features on Demand install?  If so, I would not know to look there for the subsequent remove/ install.
I have since moved on to a whole new workstation so I cannot repro the original problem.  But this is a good answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. Check out this workaround https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-Insiders/RSAT-missing-DNS-Server-Tools/td-p/113280

This allowed me to uninstall it even though it said it was missing files:

1.Run CMD as Admin.

2.Find the name of the package by typing the following, and then hitting Enter.
dism /online /Get-Packages 
In the results, look for the package name that contains the text RemoteServerAdministrationTools.

3.Type the following, and then press Enter to remove the package (in Name, type the name you got in step 2)
dism /online /Remove-Package /PackageName:

dism /online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Microsoft-Windows-RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Client-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10585.0
dism /online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Microsoft-Windows-RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Client-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.2

Comment: another possible fix https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8d35bcb6-011a-420c-83d7-196101e8b7eb/fall-creators-update-cannot-uninstall-rsat-kb2693643?forum=win10itprogeneral